# Play framework Controller Inheritance

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I was trying to create a Controller inheritance to check how does `Interceptions` work.

The default controller i.e. `Application.java` is like this:

```
@Before
static void display(){
    System.out.println("Interception method \"Before\" invoked!!!");
}

public static void index() {
    System.out.println("Inside index!!!");
    render();
}
```

I created a new controller named `App.java` and it is like this:

```
@With(Application.class)

public class App extends Controller {

public static void welcome(String txtName){
    render(txtName);
}

}
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

<form action="@{App.welcome()}" method="get">
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="txtName">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is `Welcome.html` file:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

Welcome ${txtName?:'Guest'}
```

I added this entry in routes file:

```
GET     /InterceptionDemo                       controllers.App.welcome
```

When I enter the name and click the button in `index.html` then I am getting an error:

```
The template App/welcome.html does not exist.
```

I am trying to use the `App.java` controller but it is not working. The `welcome.html` file is present under the `views/Application` folder where the `index.html` is also present.

Please let me know how to make it work...this is just a junk app trying it out for getting started with Play framework inheritance.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message tells you where Play is looking for the html file: in [views/]App/welcome.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried your example, and it worked just fine.  Placed the Welcome.html file in the wrong directory, and got the same error as you.  But then created the views/App directory and placed it there, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You want to move welcome.html from `views/Application` to `views/App`.